# make adb recognize android device

Tags: android, linux, adb

I connected my android devices to my pc, when I do `adb device` return List of devices attached, but this list is empty.

If I do `lsusb`, I can se de device an id :
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)

How can do to adb recognize the device and see it in List of devices ?
I'm not sure if adb debuggins is on, cause the screen is broken, and I need to access the cell phone information.

thanks.

Comment: Have you already enabled Developer Mode and USB debugging on your device?
https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-175517/

Answer (score 0):

if adb devices is coming empty there could be 2 reasons

1.Your Developer options is not turned on
2.Proper Device Drivers are not installed

Lsusb is a  just a utility for displaying information about USB buses in the system and the devices connected to them.